# How printf converting the incoming arguments?

Tags: c++, printf

I have the following implementations of add functions:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

```
unsigned add(unsigned a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

```
char* add(char* a, int b) {
    return &a[b];
}
```

```
const unsigned char add[6] = {0x8d, 0x04, 0x37, 0xc3};
```

This is the file for calling it

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" {
   int add(int a, int b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc <= 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: add A B\n\
    Prints A + B.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int a = strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);
    int b = strtol(argv[2], 0, 0);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, add(a, b));
}
```

Turns out that all implementations of add function producing the same result, no matter of a, b values (positive, negatives). How it's possible? I think that the magic happens in printf function, but I'm not sure. I took the source code from here https://github.com/cs61/cs61-lectures/tree/main/datarep1

Comment: How do you call the different versions? The add in the last line calles only the first version.

Comment: Looks cool if true. Please add how do you compile the program, used compiler options and your compiler version, the architecture you are using and operating system information.  I can't compile - doing `int add(int a, int b) {...} const unsigned char add[6];` makes my compiler say: `add redeclared as different kind of symbol`.

Comment: How does `printf` relate to any of this? The result of calling `add(a, b)` cannot be affected by anything in `printf`.

Comment: In your main file, you've only declared `int add(int a, int b)`.  So, when the compiler gets to `add` in the `printf` line, it doesn't know about the others since they are in another file, and it deduces to the only one it knows about at that time---and uses that one.

Comment: I took an example from havard cs61 course https://github.com/cs61/cs61-lectures/tree/main/datarep1

Comment: The add program reads two integers from its command-line arguments and prints their sum. To build and run it:

$ make add
c++  -std=gnu++1z -W -Wall -Wshadow -g   -MD -MF .deps/add.d -MP -O3 -o add.o -c add.cc
c++  -std=gnu++1z -W -Wall -Wshadow -g   -MD -MF .deps/addf.d -MP -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -o addf.o -c addf.cc
c++ -std=gnu++1z -W -Wall -Wshadow -g    -O3 -o add add.o addf.o
$ ./add 1 2
1 + 2 = 3

Comment: I think that %d may convert the result somehow to int

Comment: The source https://github.com/cs61/cs61-lectures/blob/main/datarep1/addf08.cc is enclosed within `extern "C"`, it's nothing like the code you posted. And all https://github.com/cs61/cs61-lectures/blob/main/datarep1/addf04.cc examples are in separate source files. Please make your post selfcontained and well explained, without external links. Preferably consult with your lecturer on parts you do not understand. Overall my opinion: stackoverflow is a bad place to _learn_ programming - it's a place for people that _know_ programming good and want to know even more.

Answer (score 1):

> How it's possible?

The generated machine code for your target machine, I guess for 32-bit version of x86, for the `add` symbol for each case of compiled source file is the same in each case and does the same in each case. Thus when executing the code with each of the symbols the function does the same - adds two numbers.

Note that writing code where the type of functions arguments or return type of a function does not "match" is a very serious bug.

> ```
> const unsigned char add[6] = {0x8d, 0x04, 0x37, 0xc3};
> ```

These are assembly encoded in raw bytes. This site https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2 tells me:

```
0:  8d 04 37                lea    eax,[edi+esi*1]
3:  c3                      ret
```

It's `lea` instruction with a `ret`, effectively adding the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out that all implementations of add function producing the same result, no matter of a, b values (positive, negatives). How it's possible?

It's possible because `add()` takes signed integers as arguments, and the `+` operator works correctly on signed integers. Signed integer arithmetic is generally supported at the processor level, so it's no big trick to implement an addition operation that respects signed values.

> I think that the magic happens in printf function

It has nothing to do with `printf()` and everything to do with the fact that the [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of negative numbers is inherently compatible with ordinary unsigned arithmetic.

> could you please explain how "char*" or an array of bytes versions work?

The versions of `add()` that take parameters other than `int` aren't relevant to the program you presented because that program only ever calls the `add(int, int)` version.

That said, the other versions implement sensible behavior for other types, e.g. `char* add(char* a, int b)` finds the character that's offset by `b` characters from the location that `a` points to, and returns the address of that character. `a[b]` essentially means `the char at location a + b*sizeof(char)`, and the `&` operator takes the address of that value.

Comment: not quite sure I follow. could you please explain how "char*" or an array of bytes versions work?

Comment: yes, thank you. I have found some explanations here http://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1310/2020/notes/l02.html
but still don't understand how it's possible to take a substring (&a[b]) but the result will be the correct sum

Comment: @Anatoly It's all just pointer arithmetic. If `a` is of type `foo *`, then `&a[b]` means "the address of the `foo` that's `b*sizeof(foo)` from `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The example program is ill-formed in C++ due to violating the One Definition Rule because it defines `add` as both a function and an array. Given that the program is ill-formed, the language gives no restriction on the behaviour of the program.

Another violation of ODR is that `extern "C" int add(int, int)` that is called in `main` is not defined at all. Note that C++ function overloads that do not have C language linkage are separate from functions have C language linkage.

Comment: The source code is stored in two files, add.cc and addf.cc. addf.cc contains the add function, defined in the natural way; add.cc contains main, the program entry point that calls add. Then there is GNUmakefile, which contains rules for building the add program from those source files.

Comment: https://github.com/cs61/cs61-lectures/blob/main/datarep1/GNUmakefile

Comment: @Anatoly `contains the add function` You've defined multiple add functions, none of which define the function declared in the file that defines `main`.

Comment: your answer doesn't explain why those completely different functions behave in the same way

Comment: @Anatoly This is the explanation: `Given that the program is ill-formed, the language gives no restriction on the behaviour of the program.` It explains everything about the behaviour of the porgram.